# BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync() returns null

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, barcode-scanner

I am trying to read the barcode data using PointOfService APIs.

I started with a blank Windows App template. Added a button and on the click of that button I have following code

```
var defaultScanner = await BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync();
```

but defaultScanner is always null.

I have added capability in Package.appxmanifest file like

```
<Capabilities>
      <DeviceCapability Name="pointOfService" />
</Capabilities>
```

I am using Adesso 4000B barcode reader.

Am I missing here something?

There is another method BarcodeScanner.FromIdAsync(string deviceId)

Can anybody please tell me from where I can get the deviceId of the attached Barcode Scanner? Tried looking in the properties of Barcode Scanner in Devices and Printers but there is no specific property called as DeviceId.

Answer (score 0):

The scanner must be in USB HID mode for it to be accessed by the POS API's.  You will find the programming instructions in the manual for your particular unit.

For the Adesso 4000B, I don't actually see the option for USB HID in the [programming manual](http://www.adesso.com/download/user-manual/NuScan%204000B%20Programming%20Manual.pdf), so it may not be supported.

Additionally, there are [certain times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498733/when-is-it-allowable-to-call-barcodescanner-getdefaultasync) in the application lifecycle when `GetDefaultAsync` seems to return `null`.  Make sure you are calling the function from a button handler, or use the [SDK Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Barcode-scanner-sample-f39aa411) to test.

Comment: I have a similar problem. The Barcode scanner TaoTronics BS014 cannot be found in my store app. Nevertheless it's showing in Windows device manager as a USB HID device. I'm guessing this is already the correct operation mode for the POS APIs, isn't it?

Comment: @Sven, If you open notepad and scan, does the barcode get typed as text?  If it does, it is operating as a HID Keyboard, not a HID Scanner.

Comment: Hi Mitch, the scanner has several operation modes: keyboard wedge, serial and wand emulation. But when putting to serial no serial port appears in the device manager. When using keyboard wedge it works in notepad. I've reinstalled the device and Windows installed drivers for "barcode reader". It seems you're right and the scanner doesn't work with HID mode.

Comment: The device is recognized in the System with the following ID: \\?\HID#VID_13BA&PID_0018#6&1b86aeb9&1&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030} - it is a HID device, but HidDevice.FromIdAsync() returns null. It seems that this is a known limitation for Barcode scanners [HID device support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182882.aspx#one)

Comment: Just a final comment: the device shows up internally as generic Keyboard - so it's blocked by usage restrictions of HID devices in store apps (see above link for clarification).