# When is it allowable to call `BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync()`?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, barcode-scanner

I am trying to use the new [Windows 8.1 Point of Service API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.pointofservice.aspx) for Barcode Scanners, and if I call [`GetDefaultAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescanner.getdefaultasync.aspx) from any of the following locations, it returns `null`.

- `App.OnLaunched`
- The first page `.Loaded`
- The first page `OnNavigatedTo`
- The first page constructor

This doesn't seem to be an issue with `DeviceCapabilities` or drivers, as it will work perfectly if I call it from:

- A button `Click` event handler
- The first page's `OnGotFocus`
- The first page's constructor if wrapped in:
  `this.Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync(e =>
  {
      var res = await BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync();
      Assert(res != null);
  });`
- Subsequent page's constructors

Which makes me suspect that you must have focus to access the POS devices, and the constructor et al. are being called prior to focus being received.

**Question:** Is there published guidance as to *when* you can call `GetDefaultAsync()`?

Answer (score 0):

Loosely following [Microsoft Sample BarcodeScanner](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner) I had no difficulty connecting a barcode scanner in `OnNavigatedTo` though the `BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync()` call is a bit nested.

I claimed the scanner in the `OnNavigatedTo` because the point of this particular page is to scan barcodes if the scanner is not found/claimed for some reason I want an error upfront I do not want the page to look and feel functional if it is not and I do not want to force the user to attempt a scan before they find out that the barcodescanner is not working.

I cannot tell you why calling in different locations was not working in your particular case without seeing more of your code, but i suggest trying the following.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        EnableScanner();
    }

private async void EnableScanner()
    {
        if (await CreateDefaultScannerObject())
        {
            // after successful creation, claim the scanner for exclusive use and enable it so that data reveived events are received.
            if (await ClaimScanner())
            {
                Task<bool> AsyncSuccess = EnableClaimedScanner();
                bool x = await AsyncSuccess;
                if (x)
                {
                    HookUpEventsClaimedScanner();
                }
            }
        }
    }
        private async Task<bool> CreateDefaultScannerObject()
    {
        if (scanner == null)
        {
            UpdateOutput("Creating Barcode Scanner object.");
            scanner = await BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync();

            if (scanner != null)
            {
                UpdateOutput("Default Barcode Scanner created.");
                UpdateOutput("Device Id is:" + scanner.DeviceId);
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateOutput("Barcode Scanner not found. Please connect a Barcode Scanner.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private async Task<bool> EnableClaimedScanner()
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            await claimedScanner.EnableAsync();
            if (claimedScanner.IsEnabled)
            {
                claimedScanner.IsDecodeDataEnabled = true;
                UpdateOutput("ClaimedScanner is now Enabled.");
                result = true;
            }
            else
                UpdateOutput("ClaimedScanner wasn't Enabled.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UpdateOutput( ex.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void HookUpEventsClaimedScanner()
    {
        claimedScanner.DataReceived += ScannerDataReceived;
        claimedScanner.ReleaseDeviceRequested += ScannerReleaseRequest;
    }
```

EDIT: I realize this question was over a year old but i found it in research for my own windows 8.1 embedded barcode scanner so I wanted to ensure it was not leading anyone else down the wrong path thinking `GetDefaultAsync` would not work in certain call situations.

Comment: I only had problems with `OnNavigatedTo` when it was the *first* page.  Once the app had focus it would work fine.

Comment: Interesting, I couldn't find anything in the Microsoft knowledgebase on this subject..  I'll have to give that a try and see If anything strange going on and comment back tomorrow with my findings.

Comment: Calling EnableScanner() in `OnNavigatedTo` in the MainPage entry point of my application works correctly.  I also received the scanner when calling `BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync()` inside of my App.xaml `OnLaunched`.  I cannot seem to reproduce your error.